# Finding a Parametrization of a straight line with a projection on a plane

Tags: calculus

[image]

Okay so I know origin means $(0,0,0)$

so I know

$x=t$

$y=bt$

$z=ct$

and then I sub in the slopes:

$x=t$

$y=-5t$

$z=35t$

But the math thing is telling me I'm wrong. I'm not sure what to do. ANy ideas? thanks.

Comment: If the projection on the xy plane is $7$ then $b = 7.$  And I am not sure where you are getting a negative sign in one case and not the other.

Comment: @DougM Yea I was lagging for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

- $y=7x$
- $z=5y$

then

$$(x,y,z)=(t,7t,35t)$$

Comment: omg it's you user again <3 much love